# Simplification of Summation in Queuing theory for queue with no after effects

Tags: probability, probability-theory, queueing-theory

I am looking at a queuing problem with no aftereffects. We have the following convention $v_{k}(t) = P({k \text{events happen in the time interval} (0,t)})$. We have the following equation we are trying to simplify and solve.

$v^\prime_k (t) = -\lambda v_k(t) + \sum_{1}^{k} p_i v_{k-i}(t)$

We use the characteristic method to solve the above DE. $F(t,x) = \sum_0^\infty v_k(t) x^k$.

Substituting in we get the following;

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = - \lambda F + \lambda \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k \sum_{l=1}^k p_l v_{k-l}(t)$

Now the book I am reading reduces the above to the following, I am not sure what I am missing here.

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = - \lambda F + \lambda \sum_{l=1}^\infty p_l x^l \sum_{q=0}^\infty v_{q}(t) x^q$

What is the magic that goes to the last step.

Comment: What book are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $v_k(t)$ is nonnegative for all $k,t$ we may use Tonelli's theorem to interchange the order of summation:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k \sum_{l=1}^kp_lv_{k-l}(t) = \sum_{l=1}^\infty p_l\sum_{k=l}^\infty x_lv_{k-l}(t).
$$
The change of variables $q=k-l$ yields
$$
\sum_{l=1}^\infty p_l\sum_{k=l}^\infty x_lv_{k-l}(t) = \sum_{l=1}^\infty p_lx^l\sum_{q=0}^\infty v_q(t)x^q.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should have realized that, thank you.

Comment: But I will think about it, l = $(1,\infty)$ and k =$(l, \infty)$ just looking at it seems right. I will think about it.

Comment: Here the bounds for summation are straightforward to determine ($k\geqslant 1$ and $1\leqslant l\leqslant k$ are equivalent to $l\geqslant 1$ and $k\geqslant l$), but I like to plot the points on a Cartesian plane to make it easier to visualize.

Comment: I got it while driving my car. This is akin to depth first vs breadth first search. I think of it as a lower triangular matrix. I visualized it fine but did not count it right, either you can go column $i = (0, \infty)$ and row $j = (i, \infty)$ which is what was done. The original went $j = (0, \infty)$ and clumns $i=(0,j)$ which is fine. I get it. I am not sure what I did wrong he first time I thought about it. I could not reason it out.